# How to change directory to a directory where a job(PID) is running in linux?

Tags: linux, bash

I can check where a job is running with

```
pwdx <PID>
```

I want to change directory into that specific directory. As of now, I just copy the directory name and 'cd' into it. What I want is a compact way of doing it. For instance, I want something like:

```
cd pwdx <PID>
```

Sorry for being sloppy!

Comment: `cd /proc/<PID>/cwd` (or `cd $(readlink /proc/<PID>/cwd)` to fool `bash` which keeps its own bogus idea of the cwd).

Comment: Notice that on any unix, the current dir is a per-process thing, not per-job thing (job = process group). The processes from a job can have different cwds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This removes the PID from the output of `pwdx` and the result becomes the argument to `cd`.

```
cd "$(pwdx <PID> | awk '{print $2}')"
```

or create a function:

```
pidcd () {
    cd "$(pwdx "$1" | awk '{print $2}')"
}
```